# Rails 3 Linkedin Gem (how to authenticate across view actions after getting tokens)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, rubygems, linkedin-api

In my session_controller.rb I have this:

```
require 'linkedin'

class SessionController < ApplicationController

  def connect

    # get your api keys at https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new(APP_CONFIG['linkedin']['apikey'], APP_CONFIG['linkedin']['secret_key'])
    request_token = client.request_token(:oauth_callback => 
                                      "http://#{request.host_with_port}/session/callback")
    session[:rtoken] = request_token.token
    session[:rsecret] = request_token.secret

    redirect_to client.request_token.authorize_url

  end

  def callback

    client = LinkedIn::Client.new(APP_CONFIG['linkedin']['apikey'], APP_CONFIG['linkedin']['secret_key'])
    if session[:atoken].nil?
      pin = params[:oauth_verifier]
      atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)
      session[:atoken] = atoken
      session[:asecret] = asecret
    else
      client.authorize_from_access(session[:atoken], session[:asecret])
    end

    redirect_to 'users/index'

  end

end
```

This works pretty well, the question I have now is how to check in the 'users/index' action whether or not the user has gone through the OAuth process for Linkedin? Here's the start of what I'm trying to do:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :html, :js, :json

      def index
          if authenticated?
              # set up a new LinkedIn client and show profile data
          else 
              redirect_to 'session/connect'
          end
      end

      ...

    private
      def authenticated?
          # what should i do here?        
          # return true if the user authenticated
          # return false if not
      end
```

I know I should probably be checking if there is some value set in the session but I'm not sure which one I'm looking for exactly. I know that in the future I'll probably move the 'authenticated?' method so it's called on all views, but for this is ok.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way I handled this problem was by saving the atoken and asecret values to a column in my user database.  Then when I needed to check if a user had gone through the OAuth process for Linkedin I would just check if those variables were present.  My callback method is very similar to yours with the addition of two lines to store atoken and asecret.

```
def callback
  @user = current_user
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new("API Key", "Secret Key")
    if session[:atoken].nil? || session[:atoken]==""
      @pin = params[:oauth_verifier]
      atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], @pin)

      #Used to Store atoken and asecret for user
      current_user.update_attribute(:link_tok, atoken)
      current_user.update_attribute(:link_sec, asecret)

    else
      client.authorize_from_access(current_user.link_tok, current_user.link_sec)
    end

    sign_in @user 
    flash.now[:success] = "You can now import data from LinkedIn to complete your profile"     
    render 'settings'
end
```

Also, just an FYI, LinkedIn has a strict policy about 3rd party applications saving user data from their API so you need to make sure you have all the right permissions in place before you do this.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer, sorry for the late response. I will try this out :)